# How do I add a new column to a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html for a website page built with Bootstrap:

```
{{ define "main" }}
{{ $pageurl := .Permalink }}
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 content-column white-background">
{{ partial "mobile_nav_toggle.html" . }}
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1 class="display-4">{{ .Title }}</h1>
         <p class="lead"> 
         <h3 style="font-weight:100;"> — was made by <i>{{ .Params.author }}</i></h3>
         </p>
         <hr class="my-4">
         <p style="font-size:20px;">Who is a student of <strong>{{ .Params.major }}</strong>, when they were in their year <strong>{{ .Params.year }}.</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-column-content">
         <br>
         <h4>Project Abstract:</h4>
         <hr>
         <p>{{ .Params.description }}</p>
         <hr>
         <div class="row" style="padding-top:100px;">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Reach out to them</h5>
                     <p>Copy a link to this page to save or reach out to them to learn more:</p>
                     <button type="button" onclick="copyStringToClipboard({{ $pageurl }});
                        " style="border-radius:2px;padding:10px;" class="btn btn-primary ">Copy Link</button>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#353535;border-color:#353535;border-radius:2px;padding:10px;">Contact Them</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:#f2f2f2;">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Browse More By:</h5>
                     <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                           {{ .Params.major }}    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                           Year {{ .Params.year }} Students   <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                           {{ .Params.tools }}    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <br>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

{{ end }}
```

I don't know how to add a new column to this. I've tried copying `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 content-column white-background">` and adding things inside it, but it just adds it below the existing content. Essentially, I want to have a new sticky column where the 'Browse more` box appears next to the jumbotron.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    {{ define "main" }}
    {{ $pageurl := .Permalink }}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 content-column white-background">
        {{ partial "mobile_nav_toggle.html" . }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1 class="display-4">{{ .Title }}</h1>
                    <p class="lead">
                    <h3 style="font-weight:100;"> — was made by <i>{{ .Params.author }}</i></h3>
                    </p>
                    <hr class="my-4">
                    <p style="font-size:20px;">Who is a student of <strong>{{ .Params.major }}</strong>, when they were
                        in their year <strong>{{ .Params.year }}.</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-column-content">
                    <br>
                    <h4>Project Abstract:</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <p>{{ .Params.description }}</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row" style="padding-top:100px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Reach out to them</h5>
                                    <p>Copy a link to this page to save or reach out to them to learn more:</p>
                                    <button type="button" onclick="copyStringToClipboard({{ $pageurl }});
                        " style="border-radius:2px;padding:10px;" class="btn btn-primary ">Copy Link</button>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        style="background:#353535;border-color:#353535;border-radius:2px;padding:10px;">Contact
                                        Them</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:#f2f2f2;">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Browse More By:</h5>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                {{ .Params.major }} <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                Year {{ .Params.year }} Students <span
                                    class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                {{ .Params.tools }} <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ end }}
```

for more info about bootstrap layout grids refer [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage 12 columns per row. You added this div for the first column

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 content-column white-background"></div>
```

Now you need to use this div.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 content-column white-background"></div>
```

If I use "col-md-7" then I will add "col-md-5" for the second column.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand the arguments better now.